# Beamer: Prevent/disable appearing individual subsection titles before actual content

Tags: beamer

Recently I started to question my decision to enable the appearance of individual subsection titles before actual content. I still want to show the outline of the upcoming section once before the section's content, however I feel that showing the same outline with an upcoming subsection title emphasized is an overkill (IMHO this approach produces too many extra slides).

Therefore, while I'm still finalizing my decision, I'd like to have an option to switch my Beamer presentation's current behavior for section outline management, controlled by the following code. What should be changed in the code for the above-mentioned alternative behavior?

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame} %<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents[
      currentsection,
      currentsubsection,
      sectionstyle=show/hide,
      subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
    ]
  \end{frame}
}
```

Comment: So you want to show sections but not subsections. Is that right?

Comment: @HarishKumar: I want to show initially the presentation's TOC (1st level only - section titles). Then, before each section's content, I want to show the section's TOC (upcoming section's title + its subsections' titles **all at once, one time**) and other sections' titles only.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) and save us  some typing?

Comment: You may read **9.6.2 Mode Specifications**. Such mechanism allows you to produce different versions of PDF. For example the familiar `article` and `handout` version; or you may create your own `overkilled` and `underkilled` version.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Sure, will post an MWE soon.

Comment: @Symbol1: I was aware of that feature (though haven't used it yet). This doesn't exactly address my immediate issue as described. However, it's definitely good to know - I'll read about it again. Your advice is appreciated.

Comment: @HarishKumar: I've posted my answer with MWE and a fix, but one small issue still remains - would appreciate, if you could take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I've already figured out my problem. The reason of the undesired behavior was that I was using **two methods** of *section outline management* **simultaneously**: *manual* (via `\tableofcontents`) and *automatic* (via `\AtBeginSection`). The following MWE with **fix** - *disabling the automatic control code* - illustrates the situation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap, trees, shadows, shapes, backgrounds, calc, fadings, positioning, decorations.pathreplacing, intersections, fit}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}

\usepackage{palatino}

\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\beamertemplateshadingbackground{gray!5}{gray!20}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% THE FIX -- LEFT FOR ILLUSTRATION -- TO BE DELETED
%\AtBeginSection[]
%{
%  \begin{frame} %<beamer>
%    \frametitle{Outline}
%    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
%    \tableofcontents[
%    currentsection,
%    currentsubsection,
%    sectionstyle=show/hide,
%    subsectionstyle=show/shaded/hide
%    ]
%  \end{frame}
%}

\begin{document}

% Produce top-level TOC
\frame{\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]}

\section{Introduction}
\frame[shrink=10]{\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]}

\subsection{Background and Problem}
\subsection{Research Goals and Questions}
\subsection{Relevance and Significance}
% Other subsections here

\section{Existing Research}
\frame[shrink=10]{\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]}

\subsection{Information Systems Success}
\subsection{Free/Libre and Open Source Software (FLOSS)}
\subsection{The Success of FLOSS}
% Other subsections here

\section{Methodology}
\frame[shrink=10]{\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]}

\subsection{Research Design}
\subsection{Measurement of Variables}
\subsection{Data Analysis}
% Other subsections here

\section{Results}
\frame[shrink=10]{\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]}

\subsection{Research Workflow: Reproducible Research Approach}
\subsection{Design of Research Software}
\subsection{Reformulated Hypotheses}
% Other subsections here

\section{Conclusions}
\frame[shrink=10]{\tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]}

\subsection{Discussion}
\subsection{Implications}
\subsection{Limitations}
\subsection{Future Research}
\subsection{Summary}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps it is more elegant to use the _automatic_ method with options, such as `subsectionstyle=hide`, instead of the _manual_ method, but I could not figure out the right combination of options for `\AtBeginSection` for the correct behavior.

Comment: Try with `\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame} %<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
    \tableofcontents[
    currentsection,
    currentsubsection,
    sectionstyle=show/show,
    subsectionstyle=show/show/hide
    ]
  \end{frame}
}` and delete all manual toc frames except the first one. I think it does what you want.

Comment: @Ignasi: Just saw your comment, accidentally. Thank you for your advice (+1). I will keep it in mind for my future Beamer "adventures".